# Convert Time of a particular time zone to other accounting daylight savings

Tags: java, time, localdatetime

I have a `DateTime` field representing a date and time, and a separate `zone` string which tells its time zone.

I want to convert the time in the `DateTime` to eastern timezone.

I found several answers explaining this, but all of them use the IANA's naming standard of zone ids of Continent/Region for conversion. I am getting the short form notation of zone ids in the `zone` field from the user which is like IST, AEST, CST, etc.
Is there a way I can convert time to eastern time format using the short notations?

**UPDATE:**
I have a limited set of time zones which can be given as input. They are as follows:

- `JST` - Japan Standard Time (+09:00)
- `CST` - China Standard Time (+08:00)
- `SAST` - South African Standard Time (+02:00)
- `GMT` - Greenwich Mean Time (00:00)
- `EST` - Eastern Time Zone (-05:00 / -04:00)
- `HKT` - Hong Kong Time (+08:00)
- `IST` - Indian Standard Time (+05:30)

The conversion strategy should take care of DST. So if input is `2021-01-06T10:30:00` and time zone given is `IST`. The method while converting this to EST should figure out if DST applies or not and do the conversion accordingly with either `-05:00` or `-04:00` as applicable.

Comment: "I am getting the short form notation of zone ids" do you have to? Are you limited to a specific subset of timezones so the short ids are unique? (e.g. "CST" definitely means "Central Standard Time", not "China Standard Time" or "Cuba Standard Time").

Comment: Yes, I have a specific subset. Also, my conversion should take care of DST. For eg. NZST - means both +12:00 and  +13:00. The conversion strategy should figure out if it is DST and adjust the time accordingly.

Comment: You wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687098/convert-localdatetime-of-a-particular-time-zone-to-a-est#comment116138795_65687098) _I have a specific subset_ Maybe map them to Java timezone ID's?

Comment: Will that take care of day light savings time?

Comment: @derek - That depends on what you map them to.  Though I would say the better plan would be to go back to their source and figure out how they got to be in this short form to begin with.  In general, abbreviations don't identify time zones uniformly or unambiguously.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out

Comment: I'll also note that you've given a pretty interesting list.  There's a bit of stuff from a few select places around the world, but not enough to come close to covering the other time zones nearby, such as other time zones in the US, Australia, Europe, or Russia.  Also, you ask for "EST Format", but EST isn't in your list.

Comment: Some of the long time zone names in your list do not refer to unique time zones, Gulf Standard Time and Central European Time. There are many time zones within those areas. A standard time doesn’t have two offsets. Probably one of them is intended for summer time (DST) instead. If I’m not mistaken, Brasília uses summer time too, but there’s only one offset in your list..

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint EST is standard time and it doesn't account for daylight savings (EDT). That is the reason why I have mentioned ET with two offsets. Meaning I want to account daylight saving internally. The user would just say ET and I need to figure out if it is EDT or EST.

Comment: @OleV.V.- Brasília abolished DST in 2019. The reason why I have two offsets is because I want to account for DST and EST internally while converting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses IANA time zone IDs in the form *region/city*. So if you can map your abbreviations to those, you can get through. For the sake of giving you working code, here’s an example **but I guarantee that some of the IDs are not the ones you want**. You will have to define your own mapping. Some of the long time zone names in your list do not refer to unique time zones, for example Gulf Standard Time and Central European Time. There are many time zones within those regions.

```
private static final Map<String, String> tzSubset = Map.ofEntries(
                Map.entry("NZST", "Antarctica/McMurdo"),
                Map.entry("AEST", "Australia/Sydney"),
                Map.entry("JST", "Asia/Tokyo"),
                Map.entry("HKT", "Asia/Hong_Kong"),
                Map.entry("CST", "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem"), // not in China
                Map.entry("SGT", "Asia/Singapore"),
                Map.entry("IST", "Asia/Calcutta"),
                Map.entry("GST", "Asia/Dubai"),
                Map.entry("MSK", "Europe/Volgograd"),
                Map.entry("SAST", "Africa/Mbabane"),
                Map.entry("CET", "Africa/Ceuta"),
                Map.entry("GMT", "Etc/GMT"),
                Map.entry("BST", "Europe/Belfast"),
                Map.entry("BRT", "America/Maceio"),
                Map.entry("ET", "America/Indiana/Winamac")
        );
private static final ZoneId targetTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/Toronto");
```

With the mapping and the desired time zone in place, the conversion is simple enough:

```
    LocalDateTime inputDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.JANUARY, 13, 23, 45);
    String inputTimeZone = "BST";
    
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(inputTimeZone, tzSubset);
    ZonedDateTime targetDateTime = inputDateTime.atZone(zone)
            .withZoneSameInstant(targetTimeZone);
    
    System.out.format("%s in %s equals %s%n", inputDateTime, zone, targetDateTime);
```

Output from this example snippet is:

> 2021-01-13T23:45 in Europe/London equals 2021-01-13T18:45-05:00[America/Toronto]

The conversion automatically accounts for summer time (DST) if either of the two time zones involved uses it.

Edit: It seems that you are assuming that the dates and times are current, not historical? You mentioned that America/Sao_Paulo dropped summer time in 2019 — so what if you have got a `LocalDateTime` from 2019 or earlier? If you don’t plan to handle those correctly, you should definitely do a range check on your date time and refuse to convert it if falls outside your intended bounds. Use the `isBefore` and/or the `isAfter` method of `LocalDateTime`.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Great explanation, does this automatically take care of daylight savings?

Comment: If you have got your time zone IDs right, it does (that’s what I meant by *The conversion uses summer time (DST) if the two time zones involved do.*)

Comment: `America/North_Dakota/New_Salem` isn't in China. ;)

Comment: Thanks, @MattJohnson-Pint, I missed the intended interpretation of that one. We may use Asia/Shanghai, Asia/Taipei, Asia/Chongqing, Asia/Harbin or Asia/Macau. I did guarantee that some of the IDs were not as desired. ;-)